# itextsharp insert text in pdf file with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I want to insert text into a pdf file with iTextSharp using the code below. Many times it works right but other times it does not work.

```
FileStream pdfOutputFile = new FileStream(pdfTemplate, FileMode.Create);
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdffile, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ownerPassword"));
PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;
//   pdfReader.Permissions = 1;
pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdfOutputFile);
AcroFields testForm = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

PdfContentByte pdfPageContents = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(index + 1);
string[] formattext = printTxt.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
float lhight = 0;
float abxt = abx;

printTxt= "Hello word";

ft = new FormattedText(printTxt, Color.Black, "Arial", EncodingType.Winansi, true, 9);
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(1, 1);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b);
Font f = new Font("Arial", 9);

pdfPageContents.BeginText();

BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, "ASCII", false);
pdfPageContents.SetFontAndSize(baseFont,20); // 40 point font
pdfPageContents.SetRGBColorFill(0, 0, 0);
float textAngle = 0;

pdfPageContents.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, printTxt, abx+3, (float)aby + 12 + lhight, textAngle);
pdfPageContents.EndText();
```

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992617/itextsharp-insert-text-to-an-existing-pdf)

Comment: my problem is that ..this code not work every time...it work on one or not work on another pdf file

Answer (score 1):

The approach I use to write text on any Pdf file is that I create text fields using a software tool PDF Nitro Professional (You can use some other software to create these fields). Once done you can then use the following pattern of code to write text on those fields.

```
string pdfTemplate = filePath;
string newFile = outputFilePath;
PdfReader PDFWriter = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
PdfStamper pdfStampDocument = new PdfStamper(PDFWriter, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStampDocument.AcroFields;
//For Text field
pdfFormFields.SetField("txtTextFieldName", "First Text");
//For Check Box Field 
pdfFormFields.SetField("chkSomeCheckBox", "Yes");
PDFWriter.Close();
pdfStampDocument.Close();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want to insert many sign image ,date and name of signer in a pdf file on a location...sign image insert right but text (name,date) not insert in pdf file

Comment: can be a format problem. Have you tried the suggestion of creating fields in the document?

Comment: ihave convert Doc to pdf and insert text. it is working . but when create pdf with image and insert text on it. it is not work

Comment: I have two images. I was convert them in Pdf file. Now i want to insert text with ItestSharp using this code. but text not inserted.

Comment: Hey the problem got solved. I was using PdfStamper.GetunderContent instead of that use GetOvercontent. It works. thanks all for your help...