# Create PDF form-fillable fields from Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

A bit of a Visual Studio 2010 newbie here, but I have developed a modest working knowledge of how to create report forms linked to a database, but I have come across something that I have yet to face.

I have created a report that has three tables on it. Tables 1 (equipment specs) and 2 (operation schedule) are linked to my database. Table 3 is a table (equipment performance audit)  that will need to be populated by the people out in the field. They will have to populate these fields in a PDF editor (Adobe) while they are out in the field and simply save them to PDF file. I do not believe there is a plan to have them to be imported back into a database table (which I think we should, but I don't help make those decisions...yet), so we don't need to worry about that.

The problem that I am facing is that I have no idea how to generate the fillable (i.e. text box?) fields for the PDF in Visual Studio, I tried inserting text boxes, but that didn't work...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [ITextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp/) library.  It will allow you to create PDF files on the fly.  I'm pretty sure that it is also able to create PDF forms as well.

ITextSharp is a port of the JAVA based IText PDF library. so most of the conceptual information that applies to IText will also apply to ITextsharp

Some code examples to help:
  - [iTextSharp — few C# examples.](http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/itextsharp-few-c-examples/)
  - [Generating PDF using ItextSharp with Footer in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/573907/Generating-PDF-using-ItextSharp-with-Footer-in-Csh)
  - [Create PDFs in ASP.NET- getting started with iTextSharp](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/80/Create-PDFs-in-ASP.NET-getting-started-with-iTextSharp)
  - [IText In Action book samples](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx)
  - [Answer to Fill PDF Form with Itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14500942/29467)

Comment: I don't have the rights nor the desire to install any additional software on my work computer. I need to know if it is possible with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Yes it is possible, You could go and create a library that will do the same job as ITextsharp.  But given that Itextsharp is an opensource library that is used from within visual studio to programatically create/modify PDF documents.  It is stable and reliable, and will save you months of coding.  It is available as a nuget package :- https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp/