# iTextSharp How to write SuperScript

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to write the text in Pdf using Privae font like TradGothic.
My text Contains superScript Also like- ABCCorp®. but it does not appear in Pdf, it appears as Normal Text rounded circle and R inside.

My code is

```
BaseFont TGothic20CondsdBold = BaseFont.CreateFont(strTGothicBold20Path, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
cb.SetFontAndSize(TGothic20CondsdBold, 15);
cb.SetLeading(12.5f);
cb.MoveText(187, 185);
cb.ShowText("ABCCorp®");
cb.EndText();
```

I'm using PdfStamper to write the text over existing layout.

```
//Use a PdfStamper to bind our source file with our output file
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
{
   //In case of conflict we want our new text to be written "on top" of any existing content
   //Get the "Over" state for page 1
   PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

   cb.BeginText();
   //Set the font information for heading
}
```

Any help with working sample code will be higly apppriciated.

PS:- i have also tried equivalent HTML and othe code for at the rate R , but nothing works

Answer (score 2):

Please read the official documentation. Why don't you use `ColumnText` to add the content? Using `BeginText()`, `SetFontAndSize()`, `ShowText()`, `EndText()` is for specialists, not for developers who aren't familiar with PDF.

If you use `ColumnText`, you can use high-level objects, for instance the `Chunk` object with the `SetTextRise()` method (see Listing 2.2 in [Chapter 2 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf) and also take a look at [the C# port of the Java examples](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C02)).

Comment: I have found the working sample code in CodeProject, i trust them, they have not mentioned that this code i not for developer, is there a way i can use existing code and apply superscript ?

Comment: this post also suggested same thing...Now i want to apply superscript using same way is that possible  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992617/itextsharp-insert-text-to-an-existing-pdf