Replace text in pdf using ITextSharp library with c#
I have a source pdf file. I want to replace specified texts with my c# code. I am using ItextSharp libary and below is my code:
//using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
string OrigFile = "Original.pdf";
string ResultFile = "MyPDF.pdf";
        
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(OrigFile))
{
     for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
     {
         byte[] contentBytes = reader.GetPageContent(i);
         string contentString = PdfEncodings.ConvertToString(contentBytes, "PDF");                    
         contentString = contentString.Replace(OriginalText, ReplacedText);
         reader.SetPageContent(i,PdfEncodings.ConvertToBytes(contentString, PdfObject.TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING));
     }
     new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(ResultFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)).Close();
}

This code doesn't work and my result file is not changed with replaced text.
What is the exact problem with the above?
I have tried this using ItextSharp.

You can see the answer in this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600750/itextsharp-replace-text-in-existing-pdf-without-loosing-formation

"What is the exact problem with the above??" - The exact problem is that your code only is designed to work for very simple PDF content structures and sanitized input strings. Generally the best you can hope for is that the code changes nothing while there always is the danger that it severely damages the PDF content.

Have a look at this answer (focusing on the analog problem when using PDFBox instead of iText) to get an idea why your approach generally must fail.

The problem is that PDF is a binary format, so if you would open it using  notepad++ it you would see a bunch of random bytes.
This means you can't do a simple string replace. Even if you change that string there is a super high probability that you will break the PDF as the offsets will be wrong.
That being said there are a few low level features that you can try to leverage

How to replace a text in pdf file with ITextPDF library?
https://medium.com/@sampathsl/changing-the-existing-text-in-a-pdf-d82a16219c5c
https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/replacing-pdf-objects


Strictly speaking the code shown by the OP does not apply "string replace" to what you see in an editor but it actually retrieves the decoded page content streams and works on them. Also it stores the result using the old iText PdfStamper, so offsets won't be a problem. Of course, though, even in decoded content streams string replacement is more likely to break the content than to do anything good...

As an aside, the implicit and explicit use of UTF-8 for decoding and encoding content streams in https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/replacing-pdf-objects is a bad choice and quite likely to damage the content...
