# iTextSharp PDF writer content gets cut

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have used iTextSharp to add footer note to existing pdf. Issue is when I access the pdf file and creates another file from its content, the orientation of pages gets changed and the contents get cut off. 
The code I have used is:

```
//using itextsharp
string oldFile = dtroldp + strfn;
if (File.Exists(oldFile))
{
    string newFile = strpath + "sys_" + docid + strext;

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
    int numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

     Document document = new Document();

    // open the writer
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
    writer.PageEvent = new PDFFooter();

    document.Open();

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
    {
        document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));

        document.NewPage();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

        //// select the font properties
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 32);

        // write the text in the pdf content
        cb.BeginText();

        cb.EndText();

        PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    }

    document.Close();

    fs.Close();
    writer.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
```

Can anyone suggest me what wrong I have done? Why the orientation automatically gets changed?

Comment: please attach screen shot of your generated pdf

Comment: Throw away your code. Read the [documentation](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). Read all the answers about `PdfStamper`. Feel ashamed because you didn't read the documentation first, because you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is completely wrong. Please throw away your code.

Adding content to an existing PDF is done using `PdfReader` and `PdfStamper`, **NOT** using `Document` and `PdfWriter`. Please start by reading the answer to this question: [Watermark in PDF file is hiding behind images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894122/watermark-in-pdf-file-is-hiding-behind-images)

In this example, we add some watermarks at absolute positions. In your case, you have pages with different size, so you should not use absolute positions. You should calculate the `x` and `y` value as is done in the answer to this question: [How to watermark PDFs using text or images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560373/how-to-watermark-pdfs-using-text-or-images)

You will need to know the answer to the following questions:

- [How to Get PDF page width and Height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202660/how-to-get-pdf-page-width-and-height)
- [Where is the Origin (x,y) of a PDF page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319228/where-is-the-origin-x-y-of-a-pdf-page)

Combining all this wisdom, you should be able to add a footer at the appropriate place using the appropriate classes and methods.