# Replacing text in merged pdf file

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i have a pdf file. There is a footer on each page. now i want to replace a static text exist on footer with some other text. Please Help me.....
I have tried with following case but not success

```
PdfReader readere = new PdfReader(@"D:\MergedOutput.pdf");
for (int i = 1; i < readere.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
   byte[] contentBytes = PdfEncodings.ConvertToBytes(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(readere, i), PdfObject.TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING);
   byte[] searchStringArray = PdfEncodings.ConvertToBytes("Side", PdfObject.TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING);
   byte[] replacedByString = PdfEncodings.ConvertToBytes("Hello", PdfObject.TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING);
   string searchString = PdfEncodings.ConvertToString(searchStringArray, PdfObject.TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING);
   string contentString = PdfEncodings.ConvertToString(contentBytes, PdfObject.TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING);
   string replaceString = PdfEncodings.ConvertToString(replacedByString, PdfObject.TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING);

   if (contentString.Contains(searchString))
   {
      contentString = contentString.Replace(searchString, replaceString);
   }

   readere.SetPageContent(i, PdfEncodings.ConvertToBytes(contentString, PdfObject.TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING));
}
```

Comment: Where does `PdfEncodings` comes from? What is your exact problem? Do you get any exceptions? Is the pdf not valid after saving?

Comment: Yes, Document is not valid. Its give me error on opening "There is a error on page"  PdfEncodings is the inbuilt enum in IText library.

Comment: Im am wondering what this method is for: `ConvertToString` because you can not convert a pdf to a string and than back.?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4084104/2630261

Comment: Before addressing your question I can tell you that you absolutely should not mess around with encodings like that, that will at best be a no-op but more than likely it will be things up. See [Once you have a string, you have a string, and it is Unicode, always](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10191879/231316)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a byte array of PDF data or any PDF files. First convert this file to byte array.. after that we have to apply below code section. its working fine for me...

```
 iTextSharp.text.Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Seoge UI", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(Color.FromArgb(97, 102, 116)));
    //Path to where you want the file to output
    string outputFilePath = "MergedOutputt.pdf";
    //Path to where the pdf you want to modify is
    //string inputFilePath = "D:\\MergedOutput.pdf";
    try
    {

        using (Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (Stream outputPdfStream2 = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            //Opens the unmodified PDF for reading
            var reader = new PdfReader(MergedOutputStream.ToArray());
            //Creates a stamper to put an image on the original pdf
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream) { FormFlattening = true, FreeTextFlattening = true };
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                //Creates an image that is the size i need to hide the text i'm interested in removing
                iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(new Bitmap(120, 20), BaseColor.WHITE);
                //Sets the position that the image needs to be placed (ie the location of the text to be removed)
                image.SetAbsolutePosition(reader.GetPageSize(i).Width - 120, 42);
                //Adds the image to the output pdf
                stamper.GetOverContent(i).AddImage(image, true);
                //Creates the first copy of the outputted pdf
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
                float[] width = new float[] { 38 };

                table.SetTotalWidth(width);
                PdfContentByte pb;

                //Get PdfContentByte object for first page of pdf file
                pb = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
                cellSequenceNumber = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("Side " + i.ToString(), blackFont)));
                cellSequenceNumber.Border = 0;
                table.AddCell(cellSequenceNumber);
                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, table.Rows.Count, reader.GetPageSize(i).Width - 82, 54, pb);

            }
            stamper.Close();
            //Opens our outputted file for reading
           var reader2 = new PdfReader(outputPdfStream2);
           reader2.Close();               




        }
    }
```

> It will generate a pdf file named as "MergedOutputt.pdf"