# Write a string inside a PDF file using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

In my ASP.NET MVC application, user can upload a PDF file. I want to write a string to a specific location of that file and let the user download the modified PDF. How can I do that? Is there a (hopefully free) library for this kind of task?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use iText it's the one of the best libraries available for generating PDF Files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ITextSharp insert text to an existing pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992617/itextsharp-insert-text-to-an-existing-pdf)

Comment: This question effectively asks for a library recommendation which is off topic on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you iText and there are tutorials online on how to amend an existing document:

http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-5-manipulating-existing-pdf-document