# Add text to PDF using iText7 in C#

Tags: c#, itext7

Just as the title says, I need to add text to an existing PDF file (new page at the end), using C# and itext7.  The examples on SO and the itext site all are for older versions it seems.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try? Post your code.

Comment: I have no code!  Looking for examples.

Comment: Or, more current, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68479594/1729265