# how to rotate pdf using itextsharp library

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, rotation

hi
how do we rotate PDF using itext library.
Thanks

Comment: This answer maybe able to help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579058/rotating-pdf-in-c-using-itextsharp

Comment: Are you trying to create rotated pages, or modify existing ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you writing to a new PDF document, the following line will create a new A4 page rotated (into landscape)

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example:

```
Document pdf = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdf, new FileStream("file.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create));
pdf.Open();
pdf.Add(new Paragraph("This is a pdf document!"));
pdf.Close();
```

Edit: My mistake, I read "how to **create** pdf ...". That is what the example above does. I am sorry.